# Regex in route laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Error in my route (404)

my route

```
Route::get('tg/{tg}', 'PP\PayPalController@getHooks');
```

but return contains `?`

```
https://mydoamin/tg/?code=TG-53125542=id=523651
```

How to disconsider `?` using regex on route

```
Route::get('tg/{tg}', 'PP\PayPalController@getHooks')->where('tg', regex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
Route::get('tg', 'PP\PayPalController@getHooks');
```

and handle [the GET parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string) in the function:

```
public function getHooks(Request $request) {
    $tg = $request->query('tg');
    // do something with it now
}
```

Comment: An error 404, but manualy remove `?` parameter function success.

Comment: Perfect not use variable in route {tg}